# Akeeba Backup is ready to backup your site, but there are potential issues Default Output directory in use

Tags: installation, akeebabackup, error-warning

When setting up a new installation of Joomla and installing my base components, one of these being Akeeba Pro, I now get the following warning:

> Akeeba Backup is ready to backup your site, but there are potential issues Default Output directory in use

I must stress that Akeeba still works fine, but it is annoying seeing an error warning. This has only started happening to me on new installs over the past month.

Being a little OCD, I would like to fix this error if possible. Would be nice to know also why it started happening.

p.s. I found the following in the documentation of Akeeba, but does not make any difference.

> If you just transferred or restored your site, Akeeba Backup remembers the output directory path of the site that was backed up. In this case, simply go to Akeeba Backup's Configuration page, find the Output Directory field and enter [DEFAULT_OUTPUT] (all caps, include the brackets) and click on Save.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about this warning in **Akeeba** documentation:

> Q203 - Default output directory in use

It is more like a **friendly warning** or you can say **a security warning** from the developers (not a functional warning). And it is about a relatively insecure **Output Directory** location set for akeeba backup files.

**If you set the output directory as the default directory then you will have this warning.** It is because according to the Akeeba developers (due to their understandable paranoia) the default back-up output directory is a too well known directory for hackers and it can be exploited. Thus the developers are suggesting to set an output directory for the akeeba backup files **other than the Default directory!**

You can do that in Akeeba Backup->Control Panel->Configuration->Output Directory

You can read about this with details here: https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/warnings/q203.html

Comment: I have my output directory, called /archives, above /public_html or /www in the hosting accounts root directory to keep them away from access by people who may hack the web accessible directories.

Comment: Thankyou Zollie, I do not change mine as there are never any files left there, just during the backup process. I always backup to S3 drive. I guess I have the choice to change it or live with the message :) I will change it though as one of my processes for the sake of neatness.

Comment: Perfect, it follows the guidance of changing the name of the backup directory and it worked. Thanks !!